# window.stop() isn't working onclick

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a form, that takes input, gets validated and if everything is good, I allow the request and pop up a modal that gives them the ability to *cancel* (because it takes ~2 seconds to process with a file).

```
mainForm.onsubmit = function() {
  const title = document.getElementById('grow_journal_entry_title').value;
  const notes = document.getElementById('grow_journal_entry_notes').value;
  const file = document.getElementById('file').value;
  // Check if the FILE was inputted, because the title and notes are HTML validated
  if (title && notes){
    if (file){
      // display modal
      modal.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
      // Focus on the #upload-button-area div.
      document.getElementById('upload-button-area').focus();
      alert("Please attach a photo to your journal entry.");
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

Makes sense, but now,here is how I have my "cancel" function.

```
cancelBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  window.stop();
  console.log('Cancel button clicked.');
  modal.style.display = "none";
  return false
});
```

However, everything works, except **the request still goes through**. The console prints out `Cancel button clicked`, the modal closes, but for some reason the `window.stop()` isn't doing anything.

I even tried to do this:

```
<input id="cancelUpload" class="btn advance-btn sub-text-secondary btn-secondary-col" value="Cancel Upload" type="submit" onclick="stopSubmission()">
```

And:

```
function stopSubmission(){
  try {
    window.stop();
  } catch (exception) {
    document.execCommand('Stop');
  }
  console.log("Should have stopped.")
}
```

Comment: well if the submission has already made it to the server not sure how you would stop it....

Comment: You can't supply a cancel like this; if you send the file to the server then there is no cancelling it. The cancel would simply have to ask the server to delete the file.

Comment: This doesn't look like a reliable solution -- back-end may receive the request even with window.stop().

Comment: What if I wrap it in a timeout() function? I want to give the ability to cancel.

Comment: `return window.confirm("Are You Sure?")`

Comment: The reason I was adding this was because sometimes it takes up to 5 seconds for the request to go through. I thought by doing window.stop() it would work.

Comment: Once the server starts processing the request there is nothing the browser can do to stop it. What you are going to need to do is have your server support cancelation and when the use cancels send a quick post telling the server to stop processing.

Comment: try this `window.onload=function() {
  mainForm.onsubmit=function() {
    if (title && notes){
    if (file){
      // display modal
      modal.style.display = "block";
      return true;//allow submit
    }else{
     modal.style.display = "none";
    return false; //cancel submit 
    }
   
  }
}`